# Is there any way to port forward if my router's wan IP is different from my public IP?

Tags: firewall, proxy, ip, port-forwarding

I am not using a VPN or any proxy settings, and the WAN IP address on my router's interface and IP address when searched on Google doesn't match up.

As far as I understand, my ISP is using a different router behind my router to protect with p2p connections(?) or to not end up with shortage of ipv4 addresses.

Due to this, port forwarding fails, and I want to host a game server on my laptop. Is there any way I can port forward for server?

Comment: You need to ask your operator for a connection with public IP address. Or you can set up a VPS and forward VPS server's public IP to your home.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes I did talk to my ISP and he didn't understand anything what am I talking about. I will try VPS. Thank you.

Comment: you might be behind some sort of CGNAT, check if you perhaps get an routeable ipv6

Comment: Home networking questions are off-topic here. You may be able to get help at our sister site, [su]. Though I can tell you that first level technical support generally know nothing; they just read from scripts. You have to get to second level support, and possibly third level.